# Can not run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a very simple Rails program like this. At first, I made something in Rails by this command:

`rails generate scaffold Product \ title:string desciption:text image_url:string price:decimal`

Seems everything run ok, then I ran this command `rails db:migrate` it was ok, but when I ran `rails server` I got those problem

`=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.1 application starting in development
=> Run rails server --help for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.0 (ruby 2.6.4-p104), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop`

`Started GET "/products" for ::1 at 2019-12-03 14:29:37 +0700
   (3.0ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC`

`SyntaxError (C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/X/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
...ams.require(:product).permit(:\, :title, :desciption, :image...
...^):`

`app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected backslash, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END`

I am very confuse because of this problem? I am a newbie and trying to make a simple program, so please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: please, paste `app/controllers/products_controller.rb`

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 72 in your `ProductsController`

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, in `products_controller` there's a typo in this line

```
params.require(:product).permit(:\, :title, ...)
```

Remove `:\` from the list and try again.